# why not SO introduce language grades for users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wonder SO doesn't have language grades for users, I would love to get grades on my accepted answers and asked questions depending on tagging. and one more following an expert not following a tag?

language grading is helpful to know peoples expertise languages, and user's proficiency on language.

giving scores to user chosen languages.

Is there any reason, not to introduce language grading.

sorry if it already exists!

Comment: Just in case: [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by language grading? You can get all sorts of data from the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: then How would I recognize the real expert to communicate and get solution in SO.

Comment: Why aren't the scores on answers, tag badges, and overall reputation sufficient?

Comment: You ask a question, and the answer that gets the most upvotes is usually the correct one. You don't need to evaluate the person who answered, only the answer itself.

Comment: @kongaraju - **Stack Exchange is not a Social Network**. You can not directly communicate to any person.

Comment: In case of doesn't get answer for my question? How can I approach an expert?

Comment: @kongaraju - You can set a bounty. But it doesn't guarantee you to get an answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions You can't start demanding a single user to help you. If you really need someone to personally help you, hire a consultant.

Comment: I don't want to meet an expert for volunteer, I will appreciate the expert based on his cost.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a wrong site for you then. There are plenty of other places where you can hire experts.

Comment: I dont want experts to work for fulltime. just to answer for my question.

Comment: so finally no one has solution to recognize and an expert in SO?

Answer (score 4):

There are "language grades" that are given, they are called [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general) and you can get them for answering questions in specific [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags).

You will earn these tag badges by answering questions in specific tags and earning upvotes.

Tag Badges are awarded in the following way:

> - Gold - You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Silver - You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Bronze - You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

There is no need to give language grades as these badges so your proficiency.

Comment: why not those badges for language expertise of users?

Comment: @kongaraju: How do you define "expertise"?

Comment: @kongaraju There are badges for programming languages (for example, [c#](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/40/c-sharp)). These tags show that the users with this badge have answered a significant number of questions within a specific tag and have many upvotes for their answers.

Comment: I already stated that based on the  answers accepted and upvoted questions.

Comment: no beginner will notice that badge and badge history?

Comment: so finally no one has solution to recognize and an expert in SO?